# Is there some French equivalent of Tae Kim's Japanese grammar guide?

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

Currently I'm learning Japanese along with French, and if anyone learns Japanese, they almost always use this [grammar guide by Tae Kim](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar), which goes over most aspects of the language in great detail.

Just curious, is there some equivalent learning tool for French? As currently I've found almost nothing that explains grammar in a way that isn't revoltingly clunky and badly written, and of course nothing quite as comprehensive as the Japanese guide I mentioned.

Also, please don't recommend physical books or any paid services, as neither are options for me right now.

Comment: Well - Japanese and French grammars are as different as can be: there won't be any parallels you'll be able to make :-) But a good thing is that the pronunciations are "compatible": good French speakers usually have a good Japanese pronunciation (neither language uses nearly as many diphtongues (if any) as English). You could try this: http://www.francaisfacile.com/.

Comment: And use *always* sparingly... I spent many many years learning Japanese, and never heard of Tae Kim. Then again a Japanese grammar guide by a Korean... Maybe not...

Comment: @dda - I agree - same here, had never heard of Tae Kim. The grammar I learnt actually was more comprehensive and more structured like a "grammar", but that's only because the professor was a linguist whose life work was to figure out a principled grammar of Japanese...

Comment: @Tirous While extremely popular, French learning doesn't have quite the same sort of cult following that Japanese learning does. Learning verb conjugation isn't quite as captivating as learning the kanji, nor nearly as difficult (if you're coming from a Western language background), and consequently people haven't devoted as many resources to coming up with tools and methods and web apps to help accomplish it. There are a good several guides I've found that profess to explain all of Japanese, but no, nothing like that for French, really.

Comment: Oh well, thx for answering m8's!

Comment: The best online French grammar i'm aware of the "Grammaire du FLE à l'intention des étudiants finnophones" (http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/990.html) which as its name indicates is intended for Finnish learners, but is in fact a good overview of most of the language, that only sometimes stops on a particular difficulty Fins might have with French. Its only drawbacks are that it's all in French, and that they focus exclusively on Standard French

Answer (score 2):

The grammar text that all French adults use is the Bescherelle http://bescherelle.com/bescherelle-la-grammaire-pour-tous-9782218952005.  The site in general seems to be helpful too

Comment: Pas seulement pour les adultes, mais aussi en primaire depuis les années 70.

Comment: Of course, but my point was that functioning -adults- use Bescherelle, it's not just for primary school.  Which I believe is what the question was about, especially since most schoolchildren have no say about their textbooks, poor things.  And the fact that the asker doesn't want physical books doesn't change what people are in fact using.

Answer (score 0):

The most used grammar reference in French is the *Bescherelle* (mostly for conjugation).

Some, however, are alos using the *Grevisse*.